# Prove linear independence of set $\{ 1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos 2x, \sin 2x, \cdots , \cos nx, \sin nx \}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra

*Prove linear independence of set $\{ 1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos 2x, \sin 2x, \cdots , \cos nx, \sin nx \}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$*

I can differentiate this set, but in such case I'll get another set (since derivative of $1$ is $0$), hence, I can't create system of equations and prove it by induction. It would be much easier without $1$.
Also, unfortunately, I know nothing about integration. "Orthogonal" solutions doesn't satisfy me simply because I don't understand them. The only "named" matrix I know is Vandermonde matrix.

I would happily show some other ideas about solving this question, but I just don't have them.

Hence, what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Write down the definition of linear independence. The replace the "abstract vectors" in the definition with the vectors (functions) given to you. You will have one equation. Derive this equation and you will have another equation and so on. I suggest you start by working with the set $\{ 1, \cos x, \sin x\}$ to get you going.

Comment: Orthogonality though is perhaps the easiest way to go. If this is a preparatory exercise to go into Fourier analysis, say, then you have an inner product. Prove the given functions are orthogonal, and since none of them is zero...voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make use of the following well-known result (there are plenty of easy and nice proofs of it) of Vandermonde.

> **Proposition ([The Vandermonde Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)).**
> $$\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1\\
> x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \dots & x_{n-1} & x_n\\
> x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & \dots & x_{n-1}^2 & x_n^2\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & x_3^{n-1}& \dots & x_{n-1}^{n-1}& x_n^{n-1}\\
> \end{vmatrix}=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i)$$
> Usually, it is presented with the transposed version of the matrix that I wrote. But, since the determinant is invariant under transposition, this statement is equivalent.

For some given $\lambda_0,\dots,\lambda_n,\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n\in\mathbb{R}$, consider the function $$f(x):=\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 \cos x + \mu_1 \sin x+\dots+\lambda_n\cos nx+\mu_n\sin nx=0$$ We want to show that, if $f(x)=0$ is the zero function, then every coefficient is necessarily zero. We know that $f(0)=\lambda_0+\lambda_1\dots+\lambda_n=0$. Similarly, we know that $f'(0)=\mu_1+2\mu_2+\dots+n\mu_n=0$. In general, it can be easily checked that
$$(\text{eq.} 1)\ f^{(2k)}(0)=(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^n j^{2k}\lambda_j=0\quad\text{and}\quad (\text{eq.} 2)\ f^{(2k+1)}(0)=(-1)^k\sum_{j=1}^n j^{2k+1}\mu_j=0$$
which are, in fact, two linear systems for $\Lambda:=(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and $M:=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_n)$ respectively. That is, we have that $\Lambda$ and $M$ are solutions of the linear systems (omitting signs because they are redundant)
$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 &\dots & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 2^2 &\dots & (n-1)^2 & n^2\\
0 & 1 & 2^4 &\dots & (n-1)^4 & n^4\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 1 & 2^{2n} &\dots & (n-1)^{2n} & n^{2n}\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{matrix } A\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})}\Lambda = 0,
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\dots & n-1 & n\\
1 & 2^3 & 3^3 &\dots & (n-1)^3 & n^3\\
1 & 2^5 & 3^5 &\dots & (n-1)^5 & n^5\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & 2^{2n-1} & 3^{2n-1} &\dots & (n-1)^{2n-1} & n^{2n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{matrix } B\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})}M= 0$$
We thus want to show that $\Lambda=0$ and $M=0$ are the only possible solutions since they will clearly be consistent with equations (eq.$1$) and (eq.$2$) $\forall k\geq0$. But, because $A X=0$ and $B X=0$ are square systems, this reduces to showing that $|A|,|B|\neq0$ because we already know that zero is a solution of them for being homogeneous (that is, we only have to show uniqueness). We will now make use of the said Vandermonde determinant. First of all, $|A|\neq0$ since we have that $|A|=\prod\limits_{0\leq i<j\leq n}(j^2-i^2)\neq0$. For $B$, notice that

$$\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\dots & n-1 & n\\
1 & 2^3 & 3^3 &\dots & (n-1)^3 & n^3\\
1 & 2^5 & 3^5 &\dots & (n-1)^5 & n^5\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & 2^{2n-1} & 3^{2n-1} &\dots & (n-1)^{2n-1} & n^{2n-1}\\
\end{vmatrix} = n! \begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 &\dots & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2^2 & 3^2 &\dots & (n-1)^2 & n^2\\
1 & 2^4 & 3^4 &\dots & (n-1)^4 & n^4\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & 2^{2n-2} & 3^{2n-2} &\dots & (n-1)^{2n-2} & n^{2n-2}\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

where we have just divided the $j$-th column by $j$ $\forall 1\leq j\leq n$. Hence, $|B|=n!\prod\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(j^2-i^2)\neq0$. Therefore, since we have just seen that both matrices are invertible, it is indeed the case that $\Lambda=0, M=0$ is the only possibility which proves the linear independence of the set of functions $\{1,\cos x,\sin x,\dots,\cos nx,\sin nx\}$.